# split "responseText" coming from php to 2 parts

Tags: javascript, php, html

I use:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
```

To place the result from PHP (responseText) in result div of HTML file.
How to split the result coming from PHP to two parts and put the first part in result div then replace the result div with second part?

I try:

```
  var url = "file.php";
    var params = "x1="+x1+"&x2="+x2;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
        {
           var r= xhttp.responseText.split("|");
           document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = r[0];
           document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = r[1];
        }
     }
xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhttp.send(params);
```

In php file, I put | after the end of the printed text "part 1" but, the result was:

```
This is your first part result |
```

"|" is printed! and the div does not replaced with the second part!

Comment: What does the response looks like? We need to have some kind of identifier to spilt your result.

Comment: What have you tried yet so far? Did you try your effort for researching before asking your question here?

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal the post is edited

Comment: why did you even return the part 1 if you just wanted to display the part 2?

And also, there must be something wrong with the code you have posted, are you sure there is a `|` char in the `responseText`? because that result is impossible to happen, either that `div` will contain the second part or it's just empty.

Comment: @richmondwang part1 is a statement about task progress and part 2 is the result. And yes I am sure the first part contain | char and it is displayed in the div.

Comment: if you have call the function split with `|` then why is the character `|` still printed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is working now. I solve the problem by print "|" in a separetwe echo statement.

```
echo "first statement";
echo"|";
echo"second statement";
```

Thanks all;